# Query with conditional lag statement

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to find the previous value of a column where the row meets some criteria. Consider the table:

```
| user_id | session_id | time       | referrer   |  
|---------|------------|------------|------------|  
| 1       | 1          | 2018-01-01 | [NULL]     |  
| 1       | 2          | 2018-02-01 | google.com |  
| 1       | 3          | 2018-03-01 | google.com |
```

I want to find, for each session, the previous value of session_id where the referrer is NULL. So, for the second AND third rows, the value of `parent_session_id` should be 1.

However, by just using `lag(session_id) over (partition by user_id order by time)`, I will get `parent_session_id`=2 for the 3rd row.

I suspect it can be done using a combination of window functions, but I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use last_value() in combination with if():

```
WITH t AS (SELECT * FROM UNNEST([ 
    struct<user_id int64, session_id int64, time date, referrer string>(1, 1, date('2018-01-01'), NULL),
    (1,2,date('2018-02-01'), 'google.com'),
    (1,3,date('2018-03-01'), 'google.com')
  ]) )

SELECT
  *,
  last_value(IF(referrer is null, session_id, NULL) ignore nulls) 
    over (partition by user_id order by time rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) lastNullrefSession
FROM t
```

Answer (score 1):

You could even do this via a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT
    session_id,
    (SELECT MAX(t2.session_id) FROM yourTable t2
     WHERE t2.referrer IS NULL AND t2.session_id < t1.session_id) prev_session_id
FROM yourTable t1
ORDER BY
    session_id;
```

Here is an approach using analytic functions which might work:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
        SUM(CASE WHEN referrer IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
            OVER (ORDER BY session_id) cnt
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    session_id,
    CASE WHEN cnt = 0
         THEN NULL
         ELSE MIN(session_id) OVER (PARTITION BY cnt) END prev_session_id
FROM cte
ORDER BY
    session_id;
```

Comment: true, but I'm hoping for a more efficient solution that doesn't involve a self join

Comment: I'm not doing a self join, but yes this may not run fast for very large tables.

Comment: yeah, the table I'm working with contains web traffic data and hence pretty huge

Comment: @Moon_Watcher I gave you an option using analytic functions.